# SEQUENCE in Ical

Tags: sequence, icalendar

I am creating two ics files programmatically with the same UID. One file has sequence number "2130669611". When I send a new ICS file with a new(greater sequence number 2230669611, I am getting the error that this is an old entry while the new sequence number is greater than the old one.
Is there a max value of the sequence number for outlook?

File 1

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  
PRODID:TTSTTS  
METHOD:REQUEST  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:XXX@xx.com  
ATTENDEE;CN=Manu Bhai;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:manu.bhai@xx.com  
DTSTART;TZID=UTC+0:20220322T080000Z  
DTEND;TZID=UTC+0:20220322T110000Z  
LOCATION:>Room.045  
TRANSP:OPAQUE  
SEQUENCE:2130669611  
UID:E00060977P00001158  
SUMMARY:Issue with SEQUENCE.  
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 < html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> </head> <body class="defaultFont"> Issue with SEQUENCE </body> </html> 
PRIORITY:5  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
BEGIN:VALARM  
TRIGGER:-PT15M  
ACTION:DISPLAY  
DESCRIPTION:Issue with SEQUENCE  
END:VALARM  
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

File 2

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  
PRODID:TTSTTS  
METHOD:REQUEST  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:XXX@xx.com  
ATTENDEE;CN=Manu Bhai;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:manu.bhai@xx.com  
DTSTART;TZID=UTC+0:20220322T080000Z  
DTEND;TZID=UTC+0:20220322T110000Z  
LOCATION:>Room.045  
TRANSP:OPAQUE  
SEQUENCE:2230669611  
UID:E00060977P00001158  
SUMMARY:Issue with SEQUENCE.  
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
 < html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> </head> <body class="defaultFont"> Issue with SEQUENCE </body> </html>   
PRIORITY:5  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
BEGIN:VALARM  
TRIGGER:-PT15M  
ACTION:DISPLAY  
DESCRIPTION:Issue with SEQUENCE  
END:VALARM  
END:VEVENT  
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally I am able to find a solution to this problem. SEQUENCE is a 32-bit integer. max value is 2147483647. so if the value is more than this. it will not work.

Comment: Documentation seems to be really light on this, and the validator at https://icalendar.org/validator.html does not show any errors. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

SEQUENCE is used to indicate a significant update.  Both of your versions look the same.  So in that sense the second one is an 'old' entry and not an update.

As far as max numbers go, the RFC5545 specification does not address that, it does state that it starts with 0 and incremented from there.  I expect the problem here is that there isn't actually a significant update, like a change in the date or time.

Your syntax also has numerous problems, it is not valid according to the specification.  (white space, linelengths, missing DTSTAMP, invalid DTSTART - mixing up form 2 and form 3 of date-time. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5etc).

Try running your ics through all the ics validators you can find, as they tend to pick up different things at different times.  Here are 2:
https://icalendar.org/validator.html
http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com/validate/ (currently bombing out early because of the whitespace in first line)

Comment: Hello Anmari, I update the ICS according to your suggestion. Results are still the same.  Maybe you create two ICS files one with sequence number 2130669611 and one with 2230669699. The last one will not update the previous one.

Comment: BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:TTSTTS
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20211202T080000Z
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:X@x.com
ATTENDEE;CN=M Bhai;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:manu.bhai@xx.com
DTSTART:20220322T080000Z
DTEND:20220322T110000Z
LOCATION:>Room.045
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:2130669611
UID:E00060977P00001158
SUMMARY:Issue with SEQUENCE.
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML>
< html><body class="defaultFont"> Issue with SEQUENCE </body> </html>
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Issue with SEQUENCE
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:TTSTTS
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220102T080000Z
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:XXX@xx.com
ATTENDEE;CN=Manu Bhai;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:manu.bhai@xx.com
DTSTART:20220322T080000Z
DTEND:20220322T110000Z
LOCATION:>Room.045
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:2230669699
UID:E00060977P00001158
SUMMARY:Issue with SEQUENCE.
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
< html><body class="defaultFont"> Issue with SEQUENCE2 </body> </html>
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Issue with SEQUENCE
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR